# I am wishing to ask the user to input a .txt file name, and re-prompt the user if the file name does not exist. How is this possible?

Tags: java, file

I am wishing to ask the user to input a .txt file name, and re-prompt the user if the file name does not exist. Below is the code that I have written to open a .txt file which has within it 10 numbers and average the numbers. If the initial user input file name is correct, the program executes as it should, but, if the input filename is incorrect, and the user then inputs the CORRECT file name as prompted, the program will continue prompt the user for a correct file name. How can this be fixed? Many thanks.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{

    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter below the name of the file you wish to import.");
    boolean flag = true;
    String fname = console.nextLine();
    File inFile = new File (fname);

    System.out.println("\nExists Returns: "+inFile.exists());
    System.out.println("\ncanRead Returns: "+inFile.canRead());
    System.out.println("\ngetAbsolutePath Returns: "+inFile.getAbsolutePath());
    while (flag){   
        while(!inFile.exists()){
            System.out.println("\nError: File Not Found. Try Again.");
            fname = console.nextLine();
            flag = true;
        }
        if (inFile.exists()){
            flag = false;    
            Scanner filescan = new Scanner(inFile);
            double sum = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i <=10; i++){
                double next = filescan.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("Grade "+i+" = "+next);
                sum += next;
            }
            System.out.println("\nAverage Grade = "+(sum/10)+"%");
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with more details.

Comment: Hi, I am somewhat familiar with debugging, and have been trying a long time to fix the above code. I have written programs in the past, where if the user inputs something other than what is allowed, then the user is prompted again until the correct input is received. The issue is I have never written a code which asks the user again if a **filename** is incorrect.

Comment: Did you consider a JFileChooser? Introducing a Swing component is not for free, but given the convenience, it may be worth it. Restricting to existing .txt files is only one of the advantages.

Answer (score 1):

This while loop: `while (flag){` is unnecessary.

If you remove it (and it's corresponding `}`), you will have a loop that waits until the user has entered a valid file, then you will have code that processes a valid file, then the program will finish.

**Edit**: As @OleVV points out below, you also need to set `File inFile = new File (fname);` again after `fname = console.nextLine();`.

Comment: Hello, thank-you for the response; I had tried this before, and just did again, but still, after being reprompted if an incorrect filename is input, followed by a new **correct** input, the user is reprompted

Comment: That's not possible if the `while (flag){` loop has been removed. Once your code processes the average grade, the main method exits.

Comment: You need to do the `inFile = new File(fname)` again after the user has typed a new file name. With this modification you should be able to get this simple solution to work.